# Using nextauth with firestoreAdapter

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, next-auth

I'm building a web application using Next.js as a framework, NextAuth.js for authentication, and Firebase 9 to add user details.

I'm trying to log users to Firebase when they sign up using LinkedIn, but for some reason, I'm unable to get the firestoreAdapter() to work. I'm trying to follow this documentation:
https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/firebase#1-google_application_credentials-environment-variable - specifically example 1.

**Below is my [...nextauth].js file:**

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import LinkedInProvider from "next-auth/providers/linkedin";
import { FirestoreAdapter } from "@next-auth/firebase-adapter";

export const authOptions = {
  callbacks: {
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      // Allows relative callback URLs
      if (url.startsWith("/")) return `${baseUrl}${url}`;
      // Allows callback URLs on the same origin
      else if (new URL(url).origin === baseUrl) return url;
      return baseUrl;
    },
  },
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
    LinkedInProvider({
      clientId: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions, { adapter: FirestoreAdapter() });
```

**and below is my layout.js file:**

```
import ClientProvider from "@/components/ClientProvider";
import SessionProvider from "@/components/SessionProvider";
import { authOptions } from "@/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import "./globals.css";

export const metadata = {
  title: "F2F - Find your co-founder",
  description: "MENA's first co-founder matching platform",
};

export default async function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className="flex flex-col bg-black/90 h-screen scroll-y-auto">
        <SessionProvider session={session}>
          <ClientProvider />
          {/* Client Provider */}
          <div>{children}</div>
        </SessionProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

**My .env.local file:**

```
GOOGLE_ID=secret
GOOGLE_SECRET=secret
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=secret
LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID=secret
LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET=secret
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=serviceAccountKey.json
```

According to the docs, the firestoreAdapter should immediately detect my .env.local GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS key value pair.

**The errors I get in the terminal is:**

```
Server Error
TypeError: resolver is not a function

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
Object.apiResolver
file:///C:/Users/USER1/Desktop/Build/f2f/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js (372:15)
process.processTicksAndRejections
node:internal/process/task_queues (95:5)
async DevServer.runApi
file:///C:/Users/USER1/Desktop/Build/f2f/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js (513:9)
async Object.fn
file:///C:/Users/USER1/Desktop/Build/f2f/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js (815:35)
async Router.execute
file:///C:/Users/USER1/Desktop/Build/f2f/node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js (243:32)
async DevServer.runImpl
file:///C:/Users/USER1/Desktop/Build/f2f/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js (432:29)
async DevServer.run
file:///C:/Users/USER1/Desktop/Build/f2f/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js (814:20)
async DevServer.handleRequestImpl
file:///C:/Users/USER1/Desktop/Build/f2f/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js (375:20)
async
file:///C:/Users/USER1/Desktop/Build/f2f/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js (157:99)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Do you literally have this in our env file? `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=serviceAccountKey.json`?

Comment: Hi. Yes. That's how I interpreted it to be. I also have the actual service account key JSON hidden with gitignore. Should I be referencing it differently?

Comment: Yeah I don't know if that'll work. I've never done it that way before. You should define FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID, FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL, and FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY individually in your `.env.local`. You can double check, but `.env.local` should automatically be .gitignored.